# T-SQL Nested Case Statement - Else Continue Nesting Case

Tags: t-sql, case-statement

In SQL Server, is there a way for nested case statements to ELSE continue the nesting CASE statement?

```
CASE
WHEN ... then
          CASE
          WHEN  ... THEN
          ELSE **[Continue to below WHEN]** END
WHEN ... then
WHEN ... then
ELSE ... END
```

Wondering if I can keep the code clean by not copy/pasting the proceeding WHEN statements into the nested CASE.

Comment: *"In MS SQL Server 2018"* There is no SQL Server 2018; the latest version is SQL Server 2019, and the version prior to that was 2017. Also, the above are `CASE` **expressions**; SQL Server does support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. As for your question, I don't really understand what you're asking here. If you're in the `THEN` of a `CASE` expression, then by definition the `WHEN` was true, so there's no need to recheck it again in a nested `CASE`.

Comment: So, for example, take the (overly simplified) expression `CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN CASE WHEN A = 1 AND B = 2 THEN 4 END END` There is no need to check that `A` has the value `1` in the inner `CASE` because you already know it has that value.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the nesting. So instead of this:

```
CASE
WHEN A then
          CASE
          WHEN B THEN C
          WHEN D THEN E
          ELSE **[Continue to below WHEN]** END
WHEN F then G
WHEN H then I
ELSE J END
```

You have this:

```
CASE
WHEN A AND B THEN C
WHEN A AND D THEN E
WHEN F then G
WHEN H then I
ELSE J END
```

A `CASE` **expression** (not statement: `CASE` cannot branch among SQL segments, only return a value) will stop at the first match, so by flattening the nesting and using and `AND` to tie in the nested conditions you will get the desired behavior.